# Why I receive error pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')

Tags: python, pyodbc

I don't understand? Why I receve error: `'HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!`When I insert date time? But when I insert Null all is work.  Please help me with it.
My code:

```
now=now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

connect = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=Study;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=yes;", autocommit=False)
cursor=connect.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
use base_for_time insert table_for_time_and_count values (Null,'"""+now+"""',Null,Null,Null)""")
connect.commit()
connect.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This might useful.

I think the issue is in your query and in your connection.

update connection:

`connect = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=*****;UID=****;PWD=****;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=yes;", autocommit=False)`

you're using executing multiple SQL statements in your single execution.

execute your statements one by one or use semicolon(;) instead between two queries.

`cursor.execute("use db_name; insert into table_name values (val1,val2,..,valn);")`